# clojure generate xml and xpaths from xsd

Tags: xml, xpath, clojure, xsd

In Clojure is there a simple way to generate some sample xml based on an xsd?
And how would you pull out the xpaths from the xml? (This seems the kind of problem that Clojure is good at.)

For example - turn this:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="USAddress">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="name"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="street" type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="city"   type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="state"  type="xsd:string"/>
   <xsd:element name="zip"    type="xsd:integer"/>
  </xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:attribute name="country" type="xsd:NMTOKEN" fixed="US"/>
 </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

To this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PurchaseOrder OrderDate="2012-12-13">
  <ShipTo country="US">
    <name>str1234</name>
    <street>str1234</street>
    <city>str1234</city>
    <state>str1234</state>
    <zip>1234</zip>
  </ShipTo>
  <BillTo country="US">
    <name>str1234</name>
    <street>str1234</street>
    <city>str1234</city>
    <state>str1234</state>
    <zip>1234</zip>
  </BillTo>
</PurchaseOrder>
```

Comment: Did you ever consider generating XML from XSD with XSLT?

Comment: I didn't consider it. I thought direct generation from Clojure would be better, however I will look into it.

Answer (score 2):

Clojure provides a really code library for XML manipulation (`clojure.data.xml`). And for XPath, then I think it is worth to have a look at: [clj-xpath](https://github.com/kyleburton/clj-xpath).
With those libraries, your case should be easier.

Comment: Thank you. I'll look at those libraries.